# Why does the following exception showing -4 index specifically instead of -1?

Tags: java, stringindexoutofbounds

I am trying to get a substring out of a string. I have written logic to provide a start index and an end index but getting below exception.
The code is:

```
final int startIndex = header.indexOf(startValue + ":")
                + (startValue + ":").length();
final int endIndex = header.indexOf(endValue + ":");
return header.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
```

The exception:

**'String index out of range: -4'
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing your string data, this question is not very answerable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here's the value I got while debugging for variable named header,
 
<html> <head></head> <body>  Sent: Thu Feb 04 19:06:38 IST 2021  From: test@test.com  To: tester1@test.com,tester2@test.com  Subject:

Comment: Also which java are you using? It seems newer java 12 gives an error specific to substring.

Comment: @matt I am using java 1.8

Answer (score 5):

The relevant code of `substring` is:

```
1965    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
1966    if (subLen < 0) {
1967        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
1968    }
```

If you see `-4` in the exception's message, this means `endIndex - beginIndex == -4`.

Obviously, `endIndex` should be larger than or equal to `beginIndex`, so that the difference won't be negative.

Looking at the full method (this version of the code seems to match your version, based on the line number - 1967 - in which the exception was thrown):

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

you can see that you would have gotten `-1` in the error message if `beginIndex` was `-1`.

But if `beginIndex` is non-negative, and `endIndex` is not too large, the number you get in the exception's message is `endIndex - beginIndex`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with the code.

Comment: Wow, this is a misleading error message from the Java API. It's not the string _index_ that is -4, it is the difference between the indexes but the message doesn't say so. I'm surprised and disappointed with this message.

Comment: @k314159 well, it depends how you look at it. When you call `str.substring(5,1)`, the index of the first character of the output String is 0, so if the beginIndex 5 is mapped to 0, the endIndex 1 should be mapped to -4, which is the invalid index.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer or correction, because I think your approach needs to change.  I suggest using a regex based approach to find all key value pairs in the body of your text.  Consider this version:

```java
String input = "<html> <head></head> <body> Sent: Thu Feb 04 19:06:38 IST 2021 From: test@test.com To: tester1@test.com,tester2@test.com Subject:";
String pattern = "\\b(\\S+): (.*?)(?= \\S+:)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: (" + m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ")");
}
```

This prints:

```
Found: (Sent, Thu Feb 04)
Found: (From, test@test.com)
Found: (To, tester1@test.com,tester2@test.com)
```

You may iterate over the text and search for whatever key/value you need.  Avoid substring operations in this case because it leaves too many edge cases open.

Comment: Thanks, Tim for the suggestion.